# CS educators collaboration communities?

Tags: collaboration

What are collaboration sites for CS teachers?

The CS Educators StackExchange is nice'n'friendly, but here are some topics I'd like to be discussed, which are outside of StackExchange policy:

- case studies: show to others direct experience when teaching a class
- honest skill transfer efficiency for a specific methodology, the real percentage of students who "got it" and became programmers or got computational thinking
- practice set tasks, which were used alongside main course
- collection of programming problems, which student found "interesting" and which turned students into love/understanding with programming
- collection of bad practice problems, which made more frustration than learning benefit

So far I haven't found any centralized resources except this StackExchange, but maybe there are others? I struggle now because I have to create practice task set for my course and really can't use the knowledge of precious generation of teachers, as information is highly decentralized.

Answer (score 4):

Strangely, just after posting a question I found a list of additional link collections:

- https://github.com/zamansky/awesome-cs-education
- https://github.com/quobit/awesome-python-in-education
- https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/3947/9632

And one chat:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174

I still think there should be more, but this is a start.

Answer (score 3):

ACM [SIGCSE](https://sigcse.org/sigcse/) has a regular and active mailing list for members. Questions on pedagogy and such are frequent there.

The College Board [APCS system](https://apcommunity.collegeboard.org) has a number of mailing lists for various interests and, again, teaching methodology is a common thread, though it can be pretty specific to Advanced Placement and its course and exam system.

Both will require membership. SIGCSE is more general and more directed at university level teaching. The College board more for secondary school. But there is a lot of overlap.

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the USA, there is also [CSTA](http://csteachers.org), for which there are no "topicality" requirements.  The chapters are led by teachers, and the meetings are among teachers.

I've found my chapter to be a useful resource for simply comparing notes and talking to other CS teachers.

Answer (score 1):

Computing At Schools (in the UK), has a forum:

https://community.computingatschool.org.uk/forums/